# UITextView Line break mode for new lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am working on an UITextView where I have many lines. The width of lines is less than the width of uitextview frame width.

I want to display ellipses when there are multiple lines which are not visible (because of uitextview height is less ) instead of showing scroll bar (I am not showing the scroll bar because the user doesnt want to see the scroller in that textview).

I have used lineBreakMode property but that does work only in one line.

Comment: Can u explain in detail.Wat u mean by ellipse?

Comment: @Suhail: When we have large text for ULabel which doesn't fit in that UIlabel frame and if we have set the line break mode property for that label as "NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail", in that case we can see 3 dots at the end of ULable text. I want to see the same for UITextView text but I can't use that line break mode API as it works only for one line. I do have multiple lines with small text and and after few lines I wanna put that ellipses.